# How to access Response Body of GuzzleHttp and Extract Data of Response?

Tags: php, laravel-5, response, guzzle

I'm creating application with Guzzle and Laravel 5.4. In there I'm doing request to external API and It gives response like this.

```
{
  "scope": "PRODUCTION",
  "token_type": "bearer",
  "expires_in": 3600,
  "refresh_token": "",
  "access_token": ""
}
```

And I need to access to the `access_token` property of this response. How I access these in GuzzleHttp.
Response Content type is in `application/json`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved it with this method,

```
$array = $response->getBody()->getContents();
$json = json_decode($array, true);
$collection = collect($json);
$access = $collection->get('access_token');
```